# ¿Cómo manejar errores en un Observable en Angular?

Tags: angular

Estoy iniciando en el tema de *Observable* y me encontré con la siguiente situación:

En mi `servicio.ts` obtengo una lista de libros:

```js
URL_API = 'http://localhost:4000/books';

getBooksWithAuthorName() {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.URL_API + 'AuthorName');
  }
```

En mi `componente.ts` llamo al servicio:

```js
 bookList$: Observable<Book[]>;

  constructor(public bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBooksWithAuthorName();
  }

  getBooksWithAuthorName(){
    this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName();  
  }
```

Acá mi `componente.html` donde recorro la lista con un `ngFor`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let book of bookList$ | async">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{ book.name }}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{ book.price | currency }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <div class="crop-image">
            <img [src]="linkImg(book.url_image)" alt="">
        </div>   
        <mat-card-content>
            <p>{{ book.description | slice:0:10 }}</p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Agregar al carrito</button>     
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Hasta acá todo funciona bien pero mi consulta es:

En el caso de que obtenga un error al obtener la lista en mi `componente.ts`, quisiera poder informarlo. Intente hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
 getBooksWithAuthorName(){
    // marca un error de esta forma
    this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('Todo correcto');
      },
      err => console.error('Hay un error al obtener la lista')
    );
  }
```

Pero *Angular* me informa del siguiente error:

> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Book[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un `pipe()` al observable para manejar el error.

```
this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName()
.pipe(
     catchError( error => {
       // manejo de error
       console.log(error)
       return of([])
     })
    )
```

Comment: Gracias Lobos funciona!

Answer (score 1):

otra forma de realizar el manejo de errores puede ser parecido a la forma que propusiste. Ademas es recomendable que la variable no sea tipo Observable para que puedas manipular el objeto fácil y directamente.

```
public bookList$: Book[];

getBooksWithAuthorName(){
  this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.bookList$ = res;
      console.log('Todo correcto');
    },
    err => console.error('Hay un error al obtener la lista')
  );
}
```

Comment: Gracias @David Yepes, de la forma que muestras, en el *ngFor para recorrer bookList$, no puedo utilizar el pipe async, tengo q quitarlo para que muestre la lista sin problemas. Tampoco se muy bien cual seria la diferencia  entre utilizar o no utilizar el pipe async.

Comment: Async Pipes se suele usar para comportamientos asíncronos muy complejos donde estas suscrito a ese observable pendiente de modificaciones, no se si es tu caso, pero si lo quieres quitar simplemente inicializas la variable bookList$: Book[] = []; y quitas el async en el HTML, con eso debería funcionar.